# Unable to play audio from URL on iOS using AudioPlayer package - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

When I play audio from URL using `AudioPlayer` package in flutter, it works fine on Android but on iOS it shows the below error. What could be the solution?

```
CANNOT PLAY MUSIC IN BACKGROUND. Message from code: "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003329396 "(null)""
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file audioplayer/SwiftAudioplayerPlugin.swift, line 87
2021-01-20 20:28:54.757965+0500 Runner[4397:337605] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file audioplayer/SwiftAudioplayerPlugin.swift, line 87
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [plugin home page](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer#ios)

> By default iOS forbids loading from non-https url. To cancel this
> restriction edit your .plist and add :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```